# How to have author-date citations using Springer LNCS format?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, lncs

I am using a LaTeX document similar to this, using splncsnat.bst to try to use

natbib. I also tried other options but I only obtained a bibliographic number system:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
Bla bla bla \cite[Pamp2015].

\bibliographystyle{splncsnat}
\bibliography{sbphd}   % name of my BibTeX data base
\end{document}
```

I tried this solution and it results. It is the best way?

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work OK. (Although I had to guess where you got `splncsnat.bst` from.)

```
\documentclass[oribibl]{llncs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test2018,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
  year = {2018}
}
@article{test2017a,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
  year = {2017}
}
@article{test2017b,
  author = {Author, A.},
  title = {Title2},
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
  year = {2017}
}
@article{test2016,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
  year = {2016}
}
@article{test2015,
  author = {Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C.},
  title = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {1-10},
  year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents}
\setcitestyle{round,aysep={}}
\begin{document}
\citep{test2018}

\citet[2]{test2017a}

\citep{test2018,test2017a}

\citep{test2017a,test2017b}

\citet{test2016}

\citep{test2015}

\citep[5]{test2015,test2018}
\bibliographystyle{splncsnat.bst}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, where could I get `splncsnat.bst`?

Comment: @namasikanam. No idea. I probably just Googled. Maybe http://phaseportrait.blogspot.com/2011/02/natbib-compatible-bibtex-style-bst-file.html?m=1